# COPY files into snowflake from s3 bucket: Error assuming AWS_ROLE. Please verify the role and externalId are configured correctly in your AWS policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-iam

This command in snowflake works perfectly w. this new s3 bucket our devops team has created:

```
CREATE STAGE IF NOT EXISTS test.business_tools
URL = 's3://new_bucket/'
CREDENTIALS = (aws_role = 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/s3-snowflake-blah-dev')
```

but when I try to run this command:

```
COPY INTO test_table.testing1
FROM (
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP_LTZ, METADATA$FILENAME, METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12
    FROM @test.business_tools/test_file.csv
)
```

I see this error:

> Error assuming AWS_ROLE. Please verify the role and externalId are
> configured correctly in your AWS policy.

Our devops team said the trust relationship config is OK and they've updated the IAM policy for the s3 bucket so I'm confused what else this could be. see below for the policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::new_bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::new_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The error is about incorrect trust policy configuration. Every time when stage is created/re-created it generates new AWS_EXTERNAL_ID which must match the "sts:ExternalId" in the trust policy. Run the "describe stage test.business_tools" to get the actual AWS_EXTERNAL_ID and compare it to sts:ExternalId in the trust config.

Comment: @aek - this worked for me! Thank you, can you please do "answer the question" as a comment w. the above so I can mark it as the answer!

Comment: I am glad it worked, Thanks for the confirmation. Posted an answer with a couple of docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by incorrect trust policy configuration. Every time when stage is created/re-created it generates new AWS_EXTERNAL_ID which must match the "sts:ExternalId" in the trust policy

Run:

```
describe stage <stage_name>;
```

It will print the actual AWS_EXTERNAL_ID and make sure it is the one configured as sts:ExternalId in the trust config.

Doc reference:
[Step 3 and 4](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-aws-iam-role.html)

Alternatively, Snowflake suggests using [cloud storage integration](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html) for external stages. It will allow to store the credentials in Snowflake and use them creating multiple stages.